# GET method not registering?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

So I have this code on my page:

```
<form method="get" action="client_specific_task.php">
<input type="hidden" value="x" />
<input type="submit" value="Add Client-Specific Task">
</form>
```

client_specific_task.php has the following:

```
IF (!$_GET) {
    ECHO '<html><head><title>Compliance</title></head><body><h1>Error - return home</h1></body></html>';
    die();
}
```

I am continuously getting the Error - return home message.

I've done this a million times on other pages, not sure why it isn't working this time - am I missing something obvious?

---

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Consider providing some `name` attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have no successful form controls, so `$_GET` will be empty.

A control has to have a value **and** a *name* to be successful.

Comment: wow, I had a feeling it was something obvious!  thanks *sheepish*

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `name` attribute in form input fields:

```
<form method="get" action="client_specific_task.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="x" />
    <input type="submit" name="name2" value="Add Client-Specific Task">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <form method="get" action="client_specific_task.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="x" />
 <input type="submit" value="Add Client-Specific Task">
</form>
```

You have to have a name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to determine if the user is getting.

Example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET") {
    ECHO '<html><head><title>Compliance</title></head><body><h1>Error - return home</h1></body></html>';
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said it yourself, check that it's `empty` and provide `name` to the fields

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
    // $_GET is empty
}
```

This method is secure. `!$_GET` could give you an undefined variable E_NOTICE if `$_GET` was unset.